# How do I insert pickle files to Cassandra using python?

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra, nosql, pickle, datastax-python-driver

I am trying to store n number of pickle files in cassandra using python. I didn't find much examples to store the files. Please provide example or documentation, what should be datatype for the field and the insert query.